# Javascript: Call a function after all async calls have returned

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, data is distributed across groups of table. For reading the data, I need to make `Async call` to each of these groups (1...groupCount).

I need to call another function after all the data present in each of these groups is successfully read. What is the best way to do so?

```
function getData() {

    for(var gc = 1; gc < groupCount; gc++)
        readDataFromAsync(gc);

}
```

Comment: a check-in counter variable is probably the simplest without making promises

Comment: Try the `q library` - see this example https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination it might help you

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271073/how-to-wait-for-all-xhr2-send-calls-to-finish

Comment: @PavelGatnar thanks, I will try setInterval.

Comment: @PavelGatnar Yes it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `readDataFromAsync` returns a jQuery deferred object

Use [`jQuery.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) and pass a callback to run when all is done.

```
function getData() {
  var promises = [];
  for (var gc = 1; gc < groupCount; gc++) {
    promises.push(readDataFromAsync(gc));
  }
  $.when.apply(undefined, promises).done(function(/*...*/) {
    // your code
  });
}
```

Comment: if we use as follows is there any problem?
$.when(promises).done(function(/*...*/) {
    // your code
  });

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is a bad practice to call AJAX several time, like inside of a loop.
If you can combine all the call and send all the request at a time, and take back all the response at a time then it will be best approach. For that you need to update server side code also.

But it is not possible always and depending on circumstances you need to call like this ways.

Here is some alternatives.
Use synchronous call insteted of async as follows

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '.....',
    success: function (result) {
        //.....
    },
    async: false
});
```

But it will be slow since 1 by 1 call is there and not at all a good practice.

So you could count the ajaxResponse as a variable on your successful or unsuccessful response and call a final method when ajaxResponse reach it's cap as follows.

```
var ajaxResponse  = 0;
function getData() {
    ajaxResponse= 0;
    for(var gc = 1; gc < groupCount; gc++)
        readDataFromAsync(gc);
}
function readDataFromAsync(gc) {
     $.ajax(...).success() {
       //Your current code
       ajaxResponse++;
       if(ajaxResponse>=groupCount){
             finalCall();
       }
     }
}
```

But there is problem also for the above approach. Handling ajaxResponse counter is difficult and there could be error occurred on ajax call.

You could also try setInterval and clearInterval instated of putting one if inside the success method but it will also costly.
Last one but best is approach provided by @Li Yin Kong as follows.

```
function getData() {
  var promises = [];
  for (var gc = 1; gc < groupCount; gc++) {
    promises.push(readDataFromAsync(gc));
  }
  $.when.apply(undefined, promises).done(function(/*...*/) {
    // your code
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to write this answer. But the link shared by -Gatnar  in the comment worked fine for me.